# custom method op uploading user avatar in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on rails 3.2 . I have a doubt in editting user profile. In my edit form i have avatar field to save the user image and has other fields too for updating first name , lastname, location .. Now i am trying to write a function to send a mail to the supervisor that this user has uploaded avatar. How and where to write this code logic. Should i have to add a custom validate method or how? Give suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create write into model It may be before_save or after_save, It will help you track attribute is changed or not so depending on that you can send notification.
More You can re factor by creating observer and send code to observer.

Comment: how do i know that if my avatar field gets updated because only in that cases , i would like to send notification and not whenever user updates his profile.

Comment: You can track attribute changed like self.email_changed? here i am tracking if email is changed or not more you can refer http://railscasts.com/episodes/109-tracking-attribute-changes

Comment: i already have a user_observer. Now in the user model , i added a custom after_update :function1 and added def function1 in the user model itself. Will it be possible for me to move this def function1 to user_observer??

Comment: May be changed attribute will not work as per my guess but you can try and copy the content of function1 and check it out.

Comment: I moved it  to observer. Couldn't we can render a partial inside a  observer. As i sending a message on updating user profile, i have to render a partial as the description for the message which i am not able to do ??

Comment: No even in model i am not able to use render partial

Comment: For sending email notification don't use partial